# jquery-form multiple file upload

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-file-upload

I am (trying to) use the jquery form plugin for file uploads.  I am having inconsistent behavior.  It is a lot like I am uploading too much but I don't know what parameter to change.

The form is:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  id="upload" name="upload"
        action="../php/recordInteraction.php" method="post" 
        accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

My input element looks like:

```
<input class="form-control" name="file[]" id="file" type="file"
     accept="image/jpeg" required='required' multiple='multiple'>
```

My php.ini has the following lines.

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
max_file_uploads = 4
```

When I upload smaller files, it works.  Larger files, it fails; however, I never come even close to the 40M.

When it fails, the fields from the form are not sent to my script.

When I break in the preSubmit method, I find that $.param(formData) is as expected:

```
rId=upload&file%5B%5D=%5Bobject+File%5D&file%5B%5D=%5Bobject+File%5D&file%5B%5D=%5Bobject+File%5D&upload=Upload
```

However, the script does not receive these parameters

Comment: don't forget php's memory_limit, and apache's own post size limits. there's MANY layers to a file upload, and your two php settings are only the surface of it.

Comment: Changed memory_limit from 128M -> 256M but no effect.

Comment: also don't forget to change post_max_size - files are actually sent within POST, so if it's the default 8M, you'll hit that